# Use stylesheet from cdn inside angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use a stylesheet from a cdn inside a angular component. Styles should be encapsulated inside that component only. Can't use native encapsulation mode as ie doesn't support.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please add more details to your questions like build process you are using, and what are stuffs you already tried.

Comment: @ArunVinoth - its really good question most angular 4 developer asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way you can do that in your component template. I would say to explore `ngAfterViewInit` option as most of the external thing and once the angulat template is compailed is placed in that lyfe cycle of the components.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // executes after the view is loaded
  }
}
```

if you are using angular cli you can configure them in your cli file but I think you need to download that into your asset path and give the path. I dont think cli will take cdn path.

```
  //part of cli configuration
  "prefix": "sd",
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
```